# How do I Append Multiple Rows from one Excel Table (ListObject) to Another?

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I have two tables:

```
    Table_1         Table_2
   A   B   C       A   B   C
 -------------   -------------
1| A1| B1| C1|  1| A2| B2| C2|
2| A1| B1| C1|  2| A2| B2| C2|
3| A1| B1| C1|  3| A2| B2| C2|
```

Resulting table:

```
    Table_1   
   A   B   C  
 -------------
1| A1| B1| C1|
2| A1| B1| C1|
3| A1| B1| C1|
4| A2| B2| C2|
5| A2| B2| C2|
6| A2| B2| C2|
```

Table_2 is a temporary table (ListObject) that queries a database for entries using data connection.

Table_1 is a table (ListObject) that acts as a collective list of entries.  It is kept separate because it (1) shortens the query time in Table_2 and (2) has some programmatic edits.

I have VBA code that copies Table_2 to Table_1 and then updates the connection string for Table_2 to not include entries with dates within the range of Table_1.  The result is that Table_2 only pulls new data.

My code (correctly) copies data from Table_2 to Table_1:

```
For Each temprow in Table_2.ListRows
  Set newRow = table_1.ListRows.Add
  tempRow.Range.Copy
  newRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next
```

This works great if Table_2 (new entries) only has a dozen entries. Occasionally, Table_2 will have a couple hundred entries, which will literally take 20 minutes to complete.  I suspect it's because I'm doing a couple hundred iterations of .Copy and .Paste.

Is there a way I can do it wholesale: copy ALL of Table_2 and just make it part of Table_1? I feel like what I want to do should only take 1 second to execute programmatically, not 20 minutes.  I have no conditions or exceptions.  I want EVERYTHING from Table_2, which should make it easy.  I'm probably going about it the wrong way.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can copy the .DataBodyRange in a single step.

Comment: Ron Rosenfield's response above worked for me AFTER I removed the totals rows. Maybe that's why Schmalls couldn't get it to work. I would add this as a comment, but I don't have the reputation.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this, changing the worksheet appropriately:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineTables()
    Dim LO1 As ListObject, LO2 As ListObject

With Sheet3
    Set LO1 = .ListObjects("Table_1")
    Set LO2 = .ListObjects("Table_2")
End With

LO2.DataBodyRange.Copy Destination:= _
    LO1.DataBodyRange.Offset(LO1.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count).Resize(1, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: This sent me in the correct direction. It however did not append the rows to the table, it just pasted them after the table. I had to add the step of creating a new table row at the bottom of the table and using that as the destination for my copy. For example, the last line would be replaced with: `LO2.DataBodyRange.Copy Destination:=LO1.DataBodyRange.ListRows.Add.Resize(1, 1)`

Comment: @Schmalls  It works properly without those changes here (Excel 2007), so I'm guessing there's something different about either your environment or your data.

Comment: That is weird that I had that output then. I guess mine can just be an alternate version if anyone runs into the same issue.

Comment: How could I modify this if the destination table is in another sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SQL union statement for fast table joining (ODBC):

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] UNION SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]
```

where Table 1 is on a sheet named "Sheet1" and Table 2 on "Sheet2".

Do this by going to "Data->From other sources->From Microsoft Query"

Answer (score 0):

Copy the Source table and Special paste Values + formating in temp range

- Cut the temp range
- Add a last row to the Destination Table
- Select the Last Row
- Insert the Cut selection into the Destination Table with Shift:=xlDown
- Delete the last row it you don't want it